# A field $K$ of order $q=p^r$ contains a subfield $K'$ of order $q'=p^k$ if and only if $k\mid r$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, solution-verification, finite-fields

I was trying to prove the following theorem:

> A field $K$ of order $q=p^r$ contains a subfield $K'$ of order $q'=p^k$ if and only if $k\mid r$.

My attempt at the proof was:

$K'\setminus\{0\}$ is a subgroup of $K\setminus\{0\}$. So, $p^k-1\mid p^r-1$.

From the exponent gcd lemma [$\gcd(a^x-1,a^y-1)=a^{\gcd(x,y)}-1$ when $a,x,y\in\mathbb N,a\geq 2$.]

We have that $k\mid r$.

Is this proof correct? In fact, I'm worried about this particular statement:

$K'\setminus\{0\}$ is a subgroup of $K\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: I don't understand the vote to close.  This seems like a perfectly reasonable problem.

Comment: The proof seems correct to me as far as it goes.  If you're worried about the initial step, it's easy enough for you to prove it directly.  (I assume you mean that they're subgroups under multiplication.)

But you also need to prove the other direction.

Comment: Yes, I meant they're subgroups under multiplication.

Comment: As for the other direction: I was sure about my proof of that part, which is why I didn't include it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Isn't it simpler to consider $K$ as a finite dimensional $K'$-vector space?

Comment: Then you still need to prove that if $k \vert r$ then an appropriate subfield exists.

Comment: @Bernard Yes, that was presented in my class. I was thinking about alternate proofs.

Comment: In this case, why not use that the multiplicative  group of a finite field is cyclic, and you have a cyclic subgroup of a cyclic group.

Comment: That was exactly the justification I was looking for! Thanks a lot.